# Excel SUMIF Function with Multiple Criteria for One Range (not SUMIFS)

Tags: excel

**UPDATE 2**

[image]

Here is my formula and the resulting error.  There are "#DIV/0" results in column J in some of the March data.

**END OF UPDATE 2**

---

**UPDATE**

[image]

So as you can, I am trying to sum up column J for each month (those totals will go in column R-W).  So I need to the `SUMIF` function to look at data that begins with a certain date, which I was able to figure out, but also to not include anything in the sum that is an error.

**END OF UPDATE**

I've looked around for a bit for an answer to this question but what I am finding is people are using `SUMIF` when they are looking at two different ranges; not what I'm trying to do.

I am trying to do a `SUMIFS` that looks at ONE range and has multiple criteria.

For example, I have 262,025 rows in this file.  I am trying to write a function that does a summation only if the date begins with 2016/03.  The problem is, the data I am actually summing contains some "#DIV/0" errors in it.

This is what I was thinking:

```
SUMIF(E6:E262025, AND("2016/03*", <>"#DIV/0", J6:J262025)
```

This does not work though.

Basically, I want to sum up column J only if the month is March and I want to exclude any of the values in column J that are "#DIV/0".  If this is indeed a `SUMIFS` function then my apologies.  I looked at the syntax for that function and I didn't think that was what I needed.  Looking forward to some feedback.

Comment: please post an image.

Comment: Are your dates true dates or are they static text that looks like dates?

Comment: Standby and I will post an image to illustrate.

Comment: Have you tried a pivot table. I'm quite sure it does not care about errors

Comment: I have not tried that.  I'm sure there's a very simple way to do this with some kind of `IF` same statement.  There has to be

Comment: You could also use iferror(). `=iferror(J6,0)` in a new column will copy the value of J6 if there is no error and return 0 if there is an error. Then you just do a sumif on the new column.

Comment: I was thinking that.  I just didn't want make more columns than are necessary.  Although I guess I could hide that column.

Comment: Yes just hide the column. I usually work with excel files that go to DB column and sometimes past one milion rows. Adding one column does not make any problems to your file, it's smal enough.

Answer (score 1):

A simple SUMIFS will do:

```
=SUMIFS(J:J,E:E,"<=3/31/2016",E:E,">=3/1/2016")
```

It will ignore the errors.

[image]

---

**EDIT**

Now that you posted a picture it is obvious that your dates are not actually dates but text that look like dates.  Then you can use this simple SUMIF:

```
=SUMIF(E:E,"2016/3*",J:J)
```

Again it will ignore the error.

[image]

---

**Edit #2**

If the errors are in the value column then we will need to use an array formula that ignores them:

```
=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("2016/03",E6:E262025))*(ISNUMBER(J6:J262025)),J6:J262025))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter upon exiting Edit Mode instead of Enter.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: It's not ignoring the error though.  It's reporting this as an error when I sum it up.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with array formulas in Excel because I haven't come across this problem before.  What is the multiplication for?

Comment: Also, this is giving me a result of 0.  :/

Comment: It is multiplying two Boolean values.  True = 1 and False = 0 so for it to be true both Boolean tests must equal true, if either or both are false it will be 0 or false and skip that number in the sum.  Array formulas do not like AND or OR.

Comment: Oh wait. It worked.  I forgot about the "control+shift+enter".  I've never even heard of that.

Comment: @Ryan_C it the method to tell Excel that what you just entered is an array formula, so it will iterate.

Comment: another quick question.  Let's say I wanted to sum up all of the values in a row that were greater than 100 but were also not error cells.  Do you use a `SUMIFS` for this?  I thought it might go something like this:
`=SUMIFS(A1:A10, A1:10, ">100", A1:A10, ISERROR(A1:10)=FALSE)`

I don't think that's right though.  It gives me zero no matter what I change the values in the cell to be.

Comment: @Ryan_C no SUMIFS() does not like the errors.  You would add `*(A1:10>100)` to the IF() first criterion.

Comment: Does this mean I should not have that second criteria at all?  Also, what does the multiplication do? Finally, is this even the best way to do this?  Every time I've seen SUMIFS used people have more than one column they're checking. So is there a better way to say "sum up all of the values in this column that meet whatever requirement and are not an error"?

Comment: If you had no errors then SUMIFS() would work.  With the errors it may need a different format.  The `*` means AND.

Comment: is it possible to use the `AND` function inside of `SUMIFS`? Or even better, use it inside of `SUMIF`.  For example:
`=SUMIF(A1:A10, AND(">100", "don't include any errors"))`.  If that is possible, I wasn't sure how to avoid the errors.  Would you say `AND(">100", ISERROR(A1)=FALSE)`?  The problem with that is that it's checking only A1 for the error when it really should check all of them.  If you make it A1:10 then it only work if nothing in the range is an error.  Does this get back to what you were saying about having to have an array formula?

Comment: I tried to tag you in the previous comment but I forgot and it would not let me edit that comment.

Comment: SUMIFS() will not work if your data has errors. `=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("2016/03",E6:E262025))*(ISNUMBER(J6:J262025)),IF(J6:J262025>100,J6:J262025)))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117456/discussion-between-ryan-c-and-scott-craner).